# facing issue with nginx.conf for my php application

Tags: php, nginx, debian, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am trying to configure http server for my php application in nginx but getting this error when i tring to start the service if someone can help it would be really great.

follow error i am getting when i use command to start the service

```
-- Subject: Unit nginx-rtmp.service has begun reloading its configuration
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit nginx-rtmp.service has begun reloading its configuration
Nov 22 15:54:43 chandu nginx[19339]: nginx: [emerg] pattern "^(.+\.php)(/.*)chr(36)" must have 2 captures in /opt/nginx-rtmp/conf/nginx.conf:38
Nov 22 15:54:43 chandu systemd[1]: nginx-rtmp.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 22 15:54:43 chandu systemd[1]: Reload failed for Nginx RTMP.
-- Subject: Unit nginx-rtmp.service has finished reloading its configuration
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit nginx-rtmp.service has finished reloading its configuration
-- 
-- The result is failed.
lines 1256-1284/1284 (END)
```

**My nginx.conf file**
following is my nginx.conf file  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.*)chr(36); is at line 38 where error points to above.

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 2;
pid /run/nginx-rtmp.pid;
error_log logs/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
    }
}

http {
    access_log logs/access.log;
    include mime.types;

    server {
        listen 26765;
        location /stat {
            rtmp_stat all;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        root /opt/panel/public;

        location / {
            try_files chr(36)uri /index.phpchr(36)is_argschr(36)args;
        }

        location ~ ^/index\.php(/|chr(36)) {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)chr(36);
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME chr(36)realpath_rootchr(36)fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT chr(36)realpath_root;
                internal;
            }
        location ~ \.phpchr(36) {
            return 404;
        }       
    }
}
```

**nginx-rtmp.service file**
this is my service that is created to start nginx server

```
[Unit]
Description=Nginx RTMP
After=syslog.target network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx-rtmp.pid
ExecStartPre=/opt/nginx-rtmp/sbin/nginx -t
ExecStart=/opt/nginx-rtmp/sbin/nginx
ExecReload=/opt/nginx-rtmp/sbin/nginx -s reload
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Updated nginx.config service started but getting 502 bad gateway error upon opening application on browser

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 2;
pid /run/nginx-rtmp.pid;
error_log logs/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
    }
}

http {
    access_log logs/access.log;
    include mime.types;

    server {
        listen 26765;
        location /stat {
            rtmp_stat all;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        root /opt/panel/public;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
                internal;
            }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            return 404;
        }       
    }
}
```

php-fpm.conf data

```
[global]
pid = /www/server/php/74/var/run/php-fpm.pid
error_log = /www/server/php/74/var/log/php-fpm.log
log_level = notice

[www]
listen = /tmp/php-cgi-74.sock
listen.backlog = 8192
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
listen.owner = www
listen.group = www
listen.mode = 0666
user = www
group = www
pm = dynamic
pm.status_path = /phpfpm_74_status
pm.max_children = 150
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_spare_servers = 30
request_terminate_timeout = 100
request_slowlog_timeout = 30
slowlog = var/log/slow.log
```

Comment: I don't know how you achieve that, but every `$` character occurrence somehow get changed to `chr(36)` in your nginx config. Change every `chr(36)` substring back to `$`.

Comment: ok i changed every chr(36) substring back to $ and the process started but when i am opening my application in browser its gives me error of 502 bad gateway

Comment: Update your question with your current config to make it readable.

Comment: added updated nginx.config at the end of question

Comment: Do you have the php-fpm service installed, started and actually listening on localhost TCP port 9000? What is the corresponding nginx error log message?

Comment: yes sir i do have that

Comment: `root@chandu:/opt/panel# php-fpm -t

[23-Nov-2020 07:30:12] NOTICE: configuration file /www/server/php/74/etc/php-fpm.conf test is successful`

Comment: What is the `listen` option value from `php-fpm.conf` file? What is the nginx error log message for 502 bad gateway error?

Comment: added at end of question php-fpm.conf and yes the error is bad gateway 502

Comment: Your php-fpm service is configured to listen on UNIX socket rather than HTTP port. Try `fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-cgi-74.sock;` instead of `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;`. If it does not help, show the corresponding line from nginx error log. Every 50x error gets a record in that log.

Comment: changed the fastcgi_pass  but error still same 502 bad gateway

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/569806563108323338/780338487995662346/error.log

Comment: above error log download link

Comment: The error I asked for is `2020/11/23 07:44:06 [crit] 12677#0: *138 connect() to unix:/tmp/php-cgi-74.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 117.214.72.44, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php-cgi-74.sock:", host: "recast.theirps.com", referrer: "http://recast.theirps.com/"`. It seems your php-fpm service isn't started, there is no listening socket file.

Comment: should i add `Listen 127.0.0.1:9000` in php-fpm.conf? will this gonna work?

Comment: Thanks sir made my day it worked now i changed Listen 127.0.0.1:9000 in php-fpm.conf and back to fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; in nginx.conf and reloaded both the services its working now

Comment: Didn't you understand what *service isn't started* means? You can use either UNIX socket (`listen = /path/to/socket/file`) or TCP port (`listen = <port_number>`) for php-fpm, your `fastcgi_pass` nginx directive should contain the valid parameter according to your php-fpm settings.

Comment: yes sir i got that i am newbie to nginx but your help is appreciated  thanks for it. cheers!!